# How to cite arxiv link to the reference with @incollection?

Tags: citing, arxiv

How can I add an additional arXiv link in `@incollection`? For example:

> Ritter, Jay R., 2002, Investment banking and securities issuance, in G. Constantinides, M. Harris, and R. Stulz, eds.: Handbook of the Economics of Finance (North-Holland, New York, NY), ***arxiv: blabla***.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BibTeX supports the `note` key for various types of bibliographic references (`@incollection` included), which is suitable for including arXiv links, etc.:

```
@incollection{rit2002,
  author = {Jay R. Ritter},
  ...
  note   = {arxiv: blabla}
}
```

### Edit

Regarding your comment (and assuming standard BibTeX) it is probabilly best to define something like

```
\def\arxivprefix{https://arxiv.org}
\newcommand*\arxiv[1]{\texttt{\arxivprefix/pdf/#1.pdf}}
```

and then define the `.bib` entry as

```
@incollection{rit2002,
  author = {Jay R. Ritter},
  ...
  note   = {\arxiv{1234.5678}}
}
```

Note however that this bibliography then is incompatible with documents not define `\arxiv` and that this could be a little easier using `biblatex`.

Comment: Thank you! How can I add arxiv ID as url?

Comment: You want to input the ID somewhere and get the whole url as output?

Comment: I used `\href` to address the arxiv link. But, I have one more problem. Before the link comes, I have a dot, i.e., I have `... Economics of Finance (North-Holland, New York, NY). arxiv:blabla` (the dot between NY) and arxiv). This should be a comma. How can I fix that?

Comment: And how can I have `pp 100-120` instead of `pages 100-120`?

Comment: Those last two questions are prety much unrelated to the original problem. You can simply ask new questions addressing those issues. (Keep in mind that this isn't a discussion forum. Every question has its own specific thematic purpose.)  Maybe try searching if those questions are alredy there.